# Ordering Cosmos Db Collection by property in sub-collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection of the type below:

```
[
 {
     "id": "id1",
     "Tracks": [
     {
         "id": "trackid1",
         "Usage": 
         {
             "Daily": "145",
             "Ever": "21435"
         }
     },
     {
         "id": "trackid2",
         "Usage":
         {
             "Daily": "3456",
             "Ever": " 435676"
         }
     }
     ]
 }
]
```

How do I go about getting the top 100 records ordered by the Usage Ever in descending order?

The reason for this is that we are attempting to retrieve in chunks of 100 and would like the items with the most usage to be listed first.

**Edit 1**

After the sort, the data should appear as follows:

```
[
 {
     "id": "id1",
     "Tracks": [
     {
         "id": "trackid2",
         "Usage":
         {
             "Daily": "3456",
             "Ever": " 435676"
         }
     },
     {
         "id": "trackid1",
         "Usage": 
         {
             "Daily": "145",
             "Ever": "21435"
         }
     }
     ]
 }
]
```

Comment: What does "record" refer to? Are you talking about ordering within the `Tracks` array or something related to multiple items each with multiple tracks.

Comment: @NoahStahl I really meant to say array elements. For example, there is an array of artists that returns a single artist. Under the artist is a collection of tracks, each of which contain usage. I want to sort all tracks in descending order by the Ever key in the Usage subcollection.

Comment: It's going to confuse people (or at least me :) ) to describe it rather than provide literal examples of source data and an expected result.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to find top 100, across all documents in your collection? The way you've modeled your data is not going to help you much, as you effectively would have to combine the data from every array from every document, and then sort. If it's just for a single document, just return the document and sort your resulting array/list. Not sure you're going to find a solution involving a single SELECT... All that aside: it's not very clear what, exactly, you're trying to achieve, with just a single document, a bit of results, and no query shown...

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am attempting to retrieve data for artists, which may have well over several hundred songs. I wish to retrieve the songs sorted in descending order by their usage. If I search for a single artist (i.e. 1 document for the artist), there may be several hundred songs (picture Beethoven). To limit costs and prevent throttling, I would like to retrieve the results by 100 at a time. The issue I am having is that a popular song may be stored in the second or third batch of 100 results

Comment: @LeeZ - have you considered reworking your model to store all tracks as independent documents? If you do do that, then you can query and sort on any property, and you also won't have any unbounded-array issues with your documents (where the size of the array could potentially grow your document beyond maximum size).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I do have a collection of tracks. The track info stored under artist is minimal to get me enough information in slim form so that I may query on the tracks. The artist is indexed by artist id to quickly find the artist's info. I do understand that I should possibly flatten the artist tracks/usage though but that still does not answer the question of how to get the first x tracks for the artist sorted in descending order. Otherwise, I must retrieve more tracks for the artist in the hope of sorting it after retrieval which encourages more throttling.

Answer (score 0):

That would involve using `ORDER BY` on subqueries which is not supported in CosmosDb. I would suggest doing the sorting outside database, but if you're really keen on doing it on the database side it is technically possible using user defined functions. As example:

User Defined Function:

```
function sortByString(array, sortBy) {
    return array.sort((a, b) => a[sortBy].localeCompare(b[sortBy]));
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT c.id, udf.sortByString(c.parents, 'givenName') as parents, c.children
FROM c
WHERE c.id = 'WakefieldFamily'
```

Database entry:

```
{
  "id": "WakefieldFamily",
  "parents": [
      { "familyName": "Wakefield", "givenName": "Robin" },
      { "familyName": "Miller", "givenName": "Ben" }
  ],
  "children": [
      {
        "familyName": "Merriam", 
        "givenName": "Jesse", 
        "gender": "female", "grade": 1,
        "pets": [
            { "givenName": "Goofy" },
            { "givenName": "Shadow" }
        ]
      },
      { 
        "familyName": "Miller", 
         "givenName": "Lisa", 
         "gender": "female", 
         "grade": 8 }
  ],
  "address": { "state": "NY", "county": "Manhattan", "city": "NY" },
  "creationDate": 1431620462,
  "isRegistered": false
}
```

Comment: I will see if this can be adapted to the problem I posted, but it seems like it is solving a different problem. If you look at what I am attempting to do, I am attempting to grab x subcollections sorted by values in a sub-subcollection within the subcollection x.

Comment: @LeeZ the example is more a proof of concept of what is possible. After reading the comments further I don't think this is the solution for you as it doesn't leverage the indices at all while your arrays are quite big. As David mentioned you should probably look at changing your model to allow you to query over the data but also avoid other issues (e.g. maximum document size).